# How to deal with the uncertain loops in subroutine?

Tags: loops, math, fortran

As you see, how to deal with the nn (as an input parameter) loops in the following subroutine? Or is there some better method for solving the following problem? Thanks!

```
subroutine sub(nn,kk,cc,d,res)
implicit none
integer res0,res
integer nn,kk(nn),kk2(nn),d(nn)，cc(nn) 

res=0

do kk(1)=0,d(1)
do kk(2)=0,d(2)
do kk(3)=0,d(3)
...
do kK(nn)=0,d(nn)

res0=0
kk2=kk ! They are arrays.  
call othersub(kk2,nn,res0)!So array kk should be obtained for this othersub().
res=res+res0

end do
...
end do
end subroutine
```

Comment: Maybe someone will be more successful, but I can't make heads nor tails of the question. Also, why is this tagged `[c]`?

Comment: You need to give us more information. In your example you have the loops deeply nested - is this absolutely necessary?

Comment: I agree with @Rob. It is far more likely that you can refactor this to *not* need an unknown number of loops. **But** we cannot help you without more information.

Comment: Thanks for your considerations. I added some information in the question. In fact, I also don't want to use loop. And, as you see, I want to calculate othersub(), which is related with the array kk. Is there some better way for producing this array?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt , No, I just want to use the different values of loop variables as input values for othersub(). See the question again and I changed it a little.

Comment: What version of FORTRAN is this?

Comment: This question is basically asking how to enumerate `kk^nn` in FORTRAN where `nn` is a variable parameter.

Comment: I really don't understand the question and am considering to down vote it. There is not even a question in the question. When I post a question here, I at least try to put some effort in so that others might have a clue about what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not something like  :

```
ntot=1
do i=1,nn
  ntot=ntot*(d(i)+1)
enddo

do k=1,ntot

  n=k

  do i=1,nn
    kk(i)=mod(n,d(i)+1)
    n=n/(d(i)+1)
  enddo

  !... use the array kk as you want

enddo
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways of doing this: recursive and non-recursive.  Depends on how well you can follow recursion.

```
  module NestedMod
  contains
     ! Dummy routine to do something
     subroutine Something(loop, loopMax, res)
        integer, dimension(:), intent(in):: loop
        integer, intent(in):: loopMax
        real, intent(inout):: res

        res = res + sum(loop)
     end subroutine Something

     recursive subroutine descend(current, maxDepth, loop, maxLoop, DoSomething, res)
        integer, intent(in):: current
        integer, intent(in):: maxDepth
        integer, dimension(:), intent(inout):: loop
        integer, dimension(:), intent(in):: maxLoop
        real, intent(out):: res
        interface
           subroutine DoSomething(a, asize, res)
               integer, dimension(:), intent(in):: a
               integer, intent(in):: asize
               real, intent(inout):: res
           end subroutine DoSomething
        end interface

        ! More efficient timewise to do it separately
        if (current .eq. maxDepth) then
           do ii = 0, maxLoop(current)
              loop(current) = ii
              call DoSomething(loop, maxDepth, res)      
           end do
        else
           do ii = 0, maxLoop(current)
              loop(current) = ii
              call descend(current + 1, maxDepth, loop, maxLoop, DoSomething, res)
           end do
        end if
     end subroutine descend

     subroutine ascend(maxDepth, maxLoop, DoSomething, res)
        integer, intent(in):: maxDepth
        integer, dimension(:), intent(in):: maxLoop
        real, intent(out):: res
        interface
           subroutine DoSomething(a, asize, res)
               integer, dimension(:), intent(in):: a
               integer, intent(in):: asize
               real, intent(inout):: res
           end subroutine DoSomething
        end interface
        integer, allocatable:: loop(:)
        integer:: depth

        allocate(loop(maxDepth))
        loop = -1
        depth = 1
        do while (depth .gt. 0)
           loop(depth) = loop(depth) + 1
           if (loop(depth) .gt. maxLoop(depth)) then
              ! reset loop counter
              loop(depth) = -1
              ! ascend
              depth = depth - 1
              ! off the top?
              if (depth .eq. 0) exit
           else if (depth .lt. maxDepth) then
              ! descend
              depth = depth + 1
           else
              call DoSomething(loop, maxDepth, res)
           end if         
        end do
        deallocate(loop)
     end subroutine ascend
  end module NestedMod
  program main
     use NestedMod
     integer, parameter:: DEPTH = 5
     integer, dimension(DEPTH):: loop, loopMax
     integer:: size, index
     real:: res
     loopmax = (/2, 3, 5, 2, 3 /)
     res = 0
     call descend(1, DEPTH, loop, loopMax, Something, res)
     print *, 'Recursive res = ', res

     res = 0
     call ascend(DEPTH, loopMax, Something, res)
     print *, 'Non recursive res = ', res
  end program
```